# How to restrict ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduling

I have following code which call a task after every 20 min and its working fine. Now above this i want that it only work between 0900 to 1800

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new CSDelightAlertTask(), 0, 20, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *simplest* solution would just be to wrap `CSDelightAlertTask` in a wrapper that only runs the underlying task if and only if the time is between 0900 and 1800.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use an external library, [cron4j](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/) can help for that kind of complex scheduling. Probably not worth it if this is a one off.